# How to allow only 3 types of characters between words?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a set of allowed characters:

1. apostrophe `
2. empty space
3. dash `-`

I'm struggling with building a regex which:

a. allows only one occurrence of the allowed characters between each word (any number of words are allowed)

```
E.g.
text-text    --> VALID
text text    --> VALID
text`text    --> VALID
```

b. allows combinations of allowed characters but not one after the other

```
E.g.
text-text`text    --> VALID
text text-text    --> VALID
text`text text    --> VALID
text``text  text  --> INVALID
text`text  text   --> INVALID
text`text -text   --> INVALID
```

c. doesn't allow to start with empty space   apostrophe ` or dash `-` and doesn't allow to end with apostrophe ` or dash `-` but can end with [emptyspace]

```
E.g.
text[emptyspace]  --> VALID
[emptyspace]text  --> INVALID
`text             --> INVALID
text`             --> INVALID
-text             --> INVALID
text-             --> INVALID
```

d. Special characters are not allowed at all

e. Digits are not allowed at all

This is what I have so far: https://regex101.com/r/9i3vq2/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ `-][a-zA-Z]+)* ?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkiGFH/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `` (?:[ `-][a-zA-Z]+)* `` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `` [ `-] `` - a space, backtick or `-`
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `?` - an optional space
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Is there a negation for this regex? I would also need a negated version because I have to auto-correct the invalid string

Comment: @AndreicaBogdan You cannot "negate" any regex easily because "negate" has a lot of meanings. Right now, it is not even clear what you want to auto-correct. At any rate, it is a new question.

Comment: I understand. I thought that its possible to add simple negation for reversing the above mentioned criteria. What is valid to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the answer of Wiktor to the next regex:

```regex
^[a-zA-Z]+([ `-][a-zA-Z]+)* ?$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/8wTpUv/1

Comment: You're not simplifying, you're putting more strain on the engine and generating captures that you won't need by using a capturing group.