# Prevent invalid formats based on given regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a regex for a set of [use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720225/how-to-allow-only-3-types-of-characters-between-words/60720754)

Based on that regex I'm trying to prevent the user to type invalid formats.

The regex works and preventing the user adding invalid formats also works.

The part with which I'm struggling now is that if the default value is invalid, the user cannot add additional valid characters.

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/jgqco7by/2/.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="co vi1d-" />

var previousValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*([ ]|[-])?$/g;

function validateInput(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var newValue = event.target.value || '';

    if (newValue.match(pattern)) {
        // Valid input; update previousValue:
        previousValue = newValue;
    } else {
        // Invalid input; reset field value:
        event.target.value = previousValue;
    }
}

document.getElementById('myInput').oninput = validateInput;
```

In this example since I have a default value which contains a number, which is not allowed, everything I type is replaced with previous value because the regex keeps coming back as invalid.

How could I build this so that, if the default value is invalid, the user can still add additional VALID values without having to remove the default invalid values first?

Comment: Do you mean prepending `co vi1d` to the pattern? `^co vi1d-[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*[ -]?$` http://jsfiddle.net/q7xpztsm/

Comment: No, there could be any value instead of `co vi1d-`. Because the value comes from the API. I just want to be able to add additional valid characters. Currently in my example you cannot add additional characters unless you remove the number 1.

Comment: Can't you allways let the user add change value and just mark the input with a color in your `if-else` for example?

Comment: @KamyarMirzavaziri No, I have to prevent invalid values from being added to the input. But there are currently invalid values in the DB, so in that case I have to be able to add additional valid values to the input

Comment: @AndreicaBogdan the number 1 is not valid for the pattern as it does not match digits.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I know, but that's not the issue. The issue is that I cannot write additional valid values like letters for example. The javascript code needs to change but I cant think of how can I build this

Comment: There is a 1 in `value="co vi1d-"` which will not be valid for the pattern. See https://regex101.com/r/RrHZit/1. As you say you can type when you remove the 1, that is correct because then the pattern will match. See https://regex101.com/r/hzfO9r/1 When you might do is allow digits to be present for the second part `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[ -]?$` https://regex101.com/r/yXX3Jd/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I know that. But, as I say'd in previous replies, the value comes from the DB. And if the value which comes from the DB is invalid like in my case, I have to still be able to add additional characters to the input. I know that the regex prevents me from doing that. The question is how do I change the javascript so that it lets me add additional valid characters.

Comment: Perhaps don't validate the pattern while typing, but validate the value while processing the final data.

Comment: @Thefourthbird If I was not required to validate the value while typing I wouldn't have this issue. But I have to validate the input value while typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the invalid data and a valid one in the same input I'm not seeing how it will happened with your approach.

If you want to have an initial value (that can be either valid or invalid) and then to append something (which is valid) then why are you checking for the initial state.

The third variant is to have both

- Empty field and putting a valid chars only
- Initial value (valid or invalid) and appending something (valid)

And the result will be to have a valid stuff.

Please place your question / requirement in a more structured manner.

As for the code I would suggest to change your regex. I can give suggestions for modification. :)

For the code:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="co vi1d-" />
<p id="messageField"></p>


(function() {
    const pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)*([ ]|[-])?$/g);
    const messageField  = document.getElementById('messageField');

    function validateInput(event) {
        var newValue = event.target.value; // no sense to have a check and to overwrite with window.event , its a different context
        messageField.innerText = pattern.test(newValue)  ?  '' : 'incorrect input'; // its better to use test() method rather than match()

    }

    document.getElementById('myInput').oninput = validateInput;
}());
```